# Pass a function as a data to a thread with code in a different file

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I wish to Pass a function as a data to a Threading function.

###### mainThread function - mainthread.js

```
import * as http from "node:http";
import express from "express";
import { isMainThread, Worker, workerData, threadId } from "node:worker_threads";
import { availableParallelism } from "node:os";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import * as os from "node:os";

function mainThread(url1, data = {}) {
    new Worker(fileURLToPath(url1), data);
}

export default mainThread
```

###### thread file - threads.js

```
// WISHING TO MAKE THE FOLLOWING INTO A FUNCTION TO TAKE DATA WITH FUNCTION AS ONE KEY
import * as http from "node:http";

http.createServer(workerData.listener).listen(workerData.handle, () => {
   console.log(`Listening on (threadId: ${workerData.threadId}) http://${workerData.handle.host}:${workerData.handle.port}/`);
});
```

###### mainThread file - main.js

```
import * as http from "node:http";
import express from "express";
import { isMainThread, Worker, workerData, threadId } from "node:worker_threads";
import { availableParallelism } from "node:os";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import * as os from "node:os";
import * as mainThread from "mainthread.js";

listener = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(`Hello World! (threadId: ${workerData.threadId})\n`);
};

if (isMainThread) {
    mainThread(threads.js, { workerData: listener, threadId: 1, handle: { port: 8000, host: "localhost" } })
}
```

I am wishing to make the following into a function to take function argument as data with a function in one of the keys of the object

Comment: Any help is welcome